# How to cross-compile for RasPi3

Tags: raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, qt5.7

I am currently trying to cross-compile Qt 5.7 for my Raspberry Pi 3. This is my first cross-compiling atempt, so please be kind. :)

On the Qt Wiki I found [instructions for the Raspberry Pi 2](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS), which I am currently trying to adapt.

The compile line for RasPi 2 is as follows:

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -device-option \
CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- \
-sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs \
-prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -v
```

I replaced the option

```
-device linux-rasp-pi2-g++
```

by

```
-device linux-rpi3-g++
```

as I found within the [raspi-tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) folder.

Now I am stuck at the option

```
CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

as in the `~/raspi/tools/` folder I cannot see any obviously raspi3-related entry. There is only the `arm-bcm2708/` folder. Shouldn't there be some `bcm2837` entry? Does that mean there is no support for RasPi 3 yet or am I missing something?

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arm-bcm2708/` folder is just a name. It contains several build tool chains. It's perfectly fine to use system-installed tool chains as well. So I installed the package `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf` on my build machine (Debian GNU/Linux) and used this configure call:

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rpi3-g++ \
  -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- \
  -sysroot /home/fs/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license \
  -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix /home/fs/raspi/qt5pi \
  -hostprefix /home/fs/raspi/qt5 -v
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile ICU as well with this cross-compiler?

Comment: @Mark: Not sure what you mean. I compiled qtbase and a little demo app I wrote to test the result.

Comment: I'm asking if you compiled also the QtWebkit which requires ICU. This is because there are some issues with the official cross-compiler: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/issues/41

Comment: No sorry, I did not go that far since I do not need WebKit. .. But prefer QWebEngine. QtWebKit will not be living long. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

Answer (score 3):

After much struggle (the accepted solution does not work for me), I finally got to cross compile qt 5.6 for raspberry pi 3 on ubuntu.
You basically need to follow this well known [how to](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS). Just be sure to use the following configure:

> ./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rpi3-g++
>   -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
>   -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot    -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5    -v -nomake examples -nomake
>   tests -no-use-gold-linker

Comment: Thank you for this. I wil try it the next weekend and if it works, I will mark is the preferred solution.

Comment: I don't get it -device `linux-rpi3-g++` is only available with qt5.7 right ?