# QML can using 64bit QtCreator build(compile) to 32bit

Tags: linux, qt, qml, raspberry-pi3

I just testing qml and want to build small application for my raspberry pi3. For a test I took example and compiled (using kit: Desktop Qt 5.7 GCC 64bit) and this app was working on my 64bit linux machine, but on raspberry not working (getting a lot of errors). So I guess I need compile 32bit version? and if so how can I build 32bit version of this app?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Creator is just the IDE. What you need is a Qt version [build to crosscompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615160/how-to-cross-compile-for-raspi3/37774277#37774277) for the pi3 target architecture. Then you can make a kit with it and compile projects that will run on the pi3. The kit you are currently using is compiled for a different hardware architecture, it couldn't possibly work.

You could also build Qt on the pi3 itself, which will most likely be a lot slower though, and you will have to compile your projects on it as well. I would not recommend that if you have a desktop machine.

Also, the pi3 actually has a 64bit CPU and it is possible to put 64bit linux on it, but I personally don't have the pi3 so I haven't tested it and also I don't seem to find any info on anyone succeeding with a 64bit Qt build, so you may want to do a 32bit build just to be on the safe side.

Comment: yes I see now it is head pain :) thank you for your answer!